# How to combine two models in one RoR acts_as_tree treeview?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations, acts-as-tree

I have two simple models each with acts_as_tree, say Departments and Employees.
My goal is to create a treeview combining both models in to one overall tree, like so:

- Department 1

  - SubDepartment 1.1

    - Employee A
    - Employee B
  - SubDepartment 1.2
- Department 2

  - Subdepartment 2.1

    - Employee C
- Department 3

  - SubDepartment 3.1

    - Employee D
    - Employee E
  - Subdepartment 3.2

etc

I found this already: [Acts as Tree with Multiple Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142285/acts-as-tree-with-multiple-models) but I'm afraid I could use a little more pointers in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So your schema is like this?

```
Department
  acts_as_tree  #requires departments.parent_id field
  has_many :employees

Employee
  belongs_to :department #requires employees.department_id field
```

I would just stick with this rather than trying to make the tree 'know' about employees.  The only things that have the tree relationship are the departments.  The employees belong to a department but they're not part of the tree structure.

As far as editing goes, then, when you change a department you set parent_id to be the id of its parent in the tree, and when you move an employee you set department_id to be the id of its 'parent'.

What's your actual problem?  I mean what are you trying to do?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is create a treeview build up from Departments and Employees. Not just from Departments or Employees. So the two models have to be combined in one big tree. Indeed I do have a setup as you suggest in your answer but I don't know how to expand it two combine the two models. 
Thanks for the help!